# Print Path name start with \n

Tags: c#, printing, execute

I want to print the file path as "abc\bcd\name\final" in C Sharp. But, the problem is "\n" in "name" file. How can I print this String?

edit- now I get it (special escape sequence)

Comment: Within quotes, you need to escape \ as \\, so "abc\\bcd\\name\\final". Alternatively: @"abc\bcd\name\final"

Comment: Why a down vote for this question  ?

Comment: Hey why a down vote for this. Its ok it can be a beginner type one, but still I am new to programing. You have to help beginners not crushing their hop to get into programming. I am ban now to ask question because of this.

Answer (score 1):

Simply do:

```
@"abc\bcd\name\final";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Simple do: $"abc\bcd\name\final"

Comment: Hmm, the $ means that the string shall be interpolated, but there is no `{...}` in the string. So how would this answer the question?